# Mediasoup не устанавливается при npm i mediasoup

Tags: python, node.js, cmake, msbuild, media

Запускаю команду:

```
npm i mediasoup
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
PS C:\Users\Savva\Documents\GitHub\am-server> npm i mediasoup
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Savva\Documents\GitHub\am-server\node_modules\mediasoup
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node npm-scripts.js postinstall
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] running task "postinstall"
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] buildWorker()
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] executeCmd(): make -C worker
npm ERR! make: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Savva/Documents/GitHub/am-server/node_modules/mediasoup/worker'
npm ERR! /c/Users/Savva/Documents/GitHub/am-server/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/pip/bin/meson setup \
npm ERR!        --prefix /c/Users/Savva/Documents/GitHub/am-server/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/Release \
npm ERR!        --bindir '' \
npm ERR!        --libdir '' \
npm ERR!        --buildtype release \
npm ERR!        -Db_ndebug=true \
npm ERR!        -Db_pie=true \
npm ERR!        -Db_staticpic=true \
npm ERR!        --reconfigure \
npm ERR!        --vsenv \
npm ERR!        /c/Users/Savva/Documents/GitHub/am-server/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/Release/build || \
npm ERR!        /c/Users/Savva/Documents/GitHub/am-server/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/pip/bin/meson setup \
npm ERR!                --prefix /c/Users/Savva/Documents/GitHub/am-server/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/Release \
npm ERR!                --bindir '' \
npm ERR!                --libdir '' \
npm ERR!                --buildtype release \
npm ERR!                -Db_ndebug=true \
npm ERR!                -Db_pie=true \
npm ERR!                -Db_staticpic=true \
npm ERR!                --vsenv \
npm ERR!                /c/Users/Savva/Documents/GitHub/am-server/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/Release/build
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Savva/Documents/GitHub/am-server/node_modules/mediasoup/worker'
npm ERR! /usr/bin/sh: /c/Users/Savva/Documents/GitHub/am-server/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/pip/bin/meson: No such file or directory
npm ERR! /usr/bin/sh: line 11: /c/Users/Savva/Documents/GitHub/am-server/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/pip/bin/meson: No such file or directory
npm ERR! make: *** [Makefile:110: setup] Error 127
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [ERROR] executeCmd() failed, exiting: Error: Command failed: make -C worker

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Savva\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-01T07_02_22_748Z-debug-0.log
```

Работаю на windows 10
с

nodejs: 16.19.0

npm: 8.19.3

python: 3.11.1

make: 4.3

MS Build: 16.11.2

meson: 1.0.0

ninja: 1.11.1

setuptools: 65.5.0

Comment: pip3 install meson ?

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Ошибка та же осталась